# Deployment error: windows.licensing failed to start WSService

Tags: visual-studio, windows-runtime

I get the following error when I try to deploy a windows store app:

> Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. error 0xC0020017:
>   windows.licensing failed to start WSService while installing

My developer license is valid. I changed the package name, still the error persists.

This problem occurs with old and completely new projects.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Registration of app failed error usually occurs when you try to re-deploy an app with the same package ID from visual studio if it is already installed by a different user.

Solution is to change the Package Identity

1. Open the manifest
2. Go to the package tab
3. Modify the identity

Comment: thanks, but as stated in the question, I already did that. And as i mentioned, this happens with new apps as well

Comment: Have you deleted the package from `%localappdata%\Packages` ?

Comment: First uninstall the app, then find the package folder and delete it from `%localappdata%\Packages`. Choose the unused GUID or you can also use any good name, GUID is not necessary.